# Zinc error on Team City agent

Tags: java, scala, maven, teamcity

I am trying to run zinc on every team city agent to speed up our mixed java/scala maven build.
After couple of sucessful runs zinc gives the following error:

```
Compiling 1 Scala source and 9 Java sources to /TCAgent-7.1.1/work/a731b4b8b725b627/test/target/classes...
Compiling 9 Scala sources and 42 Java sources to /TCAgent-7.1.1/work/a731b4b8b725b627/dep/target/classes...
error . does not exist or is not a directory
error . does not exist or is not a directory
info Error occurred during initialization of VM
info java.lang.Error: Properties init: Could not determine current working directory.
info at java.lang.System.initProperties(Native Method)
info at java.lang.System.initializeSystemClass(System.java:1115)
```

Both dirs exist (ls -la shows contents):

```
/TCAgent-7.1.1/work/a731b4b8b725b627/test/target/classes
/TCAgent-7.1.1/work/a731b4b8b725b627/dep/target/classes
```

This directory exists 
If I restart zinc error comes back after several runs again.
I am starting zinc with the following command:

```
zinc -start -debug
```

Here is my maven scala plugin conf:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
  <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.1.6</version>
  <executions>

  <execution>
      <id>compile</id>
      <goals>
      <goal>compile</goal>
      </goals>
      <phase>compile</phase>
  </execution>
  <execution>
      <id>test-compile</id>
      <goals>
      <goal>testCompile</goal>
      </goals>
      <phase>test-compile</phase>
  </execution>
  <execution>
      <phase>process-resources</phase>
      <goals>
      <goal>compile</goal>
      </goals>
  </execution>
  </executions>

  <configuration>
  <recompileMode>incremental</recompileMode>
  <useZincServer>true</useZincServer>
  </configuration>

</plugin>
```

Any ideas why this is happening?